# How to configure a Multi-Master Replication for MariaDB Galera Cluster in CentOS 6

Tags: mysql, database, database-backups, mariadb, multi-master-replication

I've been searching for documentations on how to configure a Multi-Master Replication in MariaDB but I can't find any. I use to try some configurations for MySQL but they didn't work. Wsrep were both ON in my two nodes but when I connect the second node to the donor, there's an error while restarting mysql. I'm using CentOS 6.4 OS. Can someone provide a documentation for MariaDB-Galera cluster Multi-Master Replication?

Answer (score 3):

See http://matthewcasperson.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/setting-up-galera-cluster-in-centos-6.html for some instructions. It runs through the process of setting up a MariaDB cluster in Centos.